# Imprimindo atributos específicos de uma tag de um arquivo XML em python

Tags: python, xml, arquivo, html-tags

Olá,

Estou começando a utilizar da linguagem Python para uma pesquisa, e como "atividade" recebi um arquivo XML do meu professor e preciso "Destrinchar" o mesmo, imprimindo conteúdos de tags e alguns atributos específicos dessas tags.
O que acontece é que sou bem iniciante na linguagem e ao tentar imprimir esses atributos não estou conseguindo.
Lendo alguns outros fóruns cheguei em um código onde eu consigo imprimir as tags do arquivo, mas não os atributos dela, já que o arquivo se trata de um exemplo de PLN, onde cada tag representa um nodo com seu atributos como id, word, text, lema e etc.
Vou deixar aqui o código, a saída atual e um pedaço do meu arquivo para melhor entendimento do problema.

Código:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import requests


arquivo = "C1_Extrato_2_Palavras.xml"
tree = ET.parse(arquivo)

root = tree.getroot()

filtro = "*"
for child in root.iter(filtro):
    print(child.tag, child.text)

print("\n")

for child in root.findall("body"):
    for esse in child.findall("graph"):
        print(esse.text)
```

Saída:

```
corpus 


body 

s 

graph 

terminals 

t None
t None
t None
t None
t None
t None
t None
t None
t None
t None
t None
t None
t None
t None
t None
t None
t None
t None
t None
t None
t None
t None
t None
t None
t None
t None
t None
t None
t None
t None
t None
t None
t None
t None
nonterminals 

nt 

edge None
nt 

edge None
edge None
edge None
edge None
nt
```

Parte do arquivo em XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<corpus>

    <body>
<s id="s1" ref="1" source="Running text" forest="1" text="Um acidente aéreo na localidade de Bukavu, no leste da República Democrática do Congo, matou 17 pessoas na quinta-feira à tarde, informou hoje um porta-voz das Nações Unidas.">
    <graph root="s1_500">
        <terminals>
            <t id="s1_1" word="Um" lemma="um" pos="art" morph="M S" extra="* "/>
            <t id="s1_2" word="acidente" lemma="acidente" pos="n" morph="M S" sem="event" extra="--"/>
            <t id="s1_3" word="aéreo" lemma="aéreo" pos="adj" morph="M S" extra="nh np-close"/>
            <t id="s1_4" word="em" lemma="em" pos="prp" morph="--" extra="sam- np-long"/>
            <t id="s1_5" word="a" lemma="o" pos="art" morph="F S" extra="-sam "/>
            <t id="s1_6" word="localidade" lemma="localidade" pos="n" morph="F S" sem="Labs Lciv" extra="--"/>
            <t id="s1_7" word="de" lemma="de" pos="prp" morph="--" extra="np-close"/>
            <t id="s1_8" word="Bukavu" lemma="Bukavu" pos="prop" morph="M/F S" extra="civ * heur"/>
            <t id="s1_9" word="," lemma="--" pos="pu" morph="--" extra="--"/>
            <t id="s1_10" word="em" lemma="em" pos="prp" morph="--" extra="sam-"/>
            <t id="s1_11" word="o" lemma="o" pos="art" morph="M S" extra="-sam "/>
            <t id="s1_12" word="leste" lemma="leste" pos="n" morph="M S" sem="dir" extra="--"/>
            <t id="s1_13" word="de" lemma="de" pos="prp" morph="--" extra="sam- np-close"/>
            <t id="s1_14" word="a" lemma="o" pos="art" morph="F S" extra="-sam "/>
            <t id="s1_15" word="República_Democrática_do_Congo" lemma="República_Democrática_do_Congo" pos="prop" morph="F S" extra="civ *"/>
            <t id="s1_16" word="," lemma="--" pos="pu" morph="--" extra="--"/>
            <t id="s1_17" word="matou" lemma="matar" pos="v-fin" morph="PS 3S IND VFIN" extra="cjt-head cjt-head-STA fmc mv"/>
            <t id="s1_18" word="17" lemma="17" pos="num" morph="F P" extra="card"/>
            <t id="s1_19" word="pessoas" lemma="pessoa" pos="n" morph="F P" sem="H" extra="--"/>
            <t id="s1_20" word="em" lemma="em" pos="prp" morph="--" extra="sam-"/>
            <t id="s1_21" word="a" lemma="o" pos="art" morph="F S" extra="-sam "/>
            <t id="s1_22" word="quinta-feira" lemma="quinta-feira" pos="n" morph="F S" sem="temp" extra="--"/>
            <t id="s1_23" word="a" lemma="a" pos="prp" morph="--" extra="sam-"/>
            <t id="s1_24" word="a" lemma="o" pos="art" morph="F S" extra="-sam "/>
            <t id="s1_25" word="tarde" lemma="tarde" pos="n" morph="F S" sem="per" extra="--"/>
            <t id="s1_26" word="," lemma="--" pos="pu" morph="--" extra="--"/>
            <t id="s1_27" word="informou" lemma="informar" pos="v-fin" morph="PS 3S IND VFIN" extra="nosubj nosubj cjt-STA vH fmc mv"/>
            <t id="s1_28" word="hoje" lemma="hoje" pos="adv" morph="--" extra="--"/>
            <t id="s1_29" word="um" lemma="um" pos="art" morph="M S" extra="--"/>
            <t id="s1_30" word="porta-voz" lemma="porta-voz" pos="n" morph="M S" sem="tool Hprof" extra="--"/>
            <t id="s1_31" word="de" lemma="de" pos="prp" morph="--" extra="sam-"/>
            <t id="s1_32" word="as" lemma="o" pos="art" morph="F P" extra="-sam "/>
            <t id="s1_33" word="Nações_Unidas" lemma="Nações_Unidas" pos="prop" morph="F P" extra="org * newlex"/>
            <t id="s1_34" word="." lemma="--" pos="pu" morph="--" extra="--"/>
        </terminals>

        <nonterminals>
            <nt id="s1_500" cat="s">
                <edge label="STA" idref="s1_501"/>
            </nt>
            <nt id="s1_501" cat="par">
                <edge label="CJT" idref="s1_502"/>
                <edge label="PU" idref="s1_26"/>
                <edge label="CJT" idref="s1_516"/>
                <edge label="PU" idref="s1_34"/>
            </nt>
```

Desculpe pelo tamanho da pergunta e pela formatação da mesma, é a primeira vez que faço uma pergunta aqui (inclusive aceito dicas/toques).

Answer (score 0):

Não sobre os usos dos outros métodos, mas sempre que utilizei este módulo, a função que eu usava para montar a árvore era `fromstring`, que recebe uma string no formato XML e retorna a raiz da árvore.

O seu código não me aparentou muito incorreto. Mas você apenas buscou nas fontes erradas sobre como aplicar seu código. Recomendo sempre ler [a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) antes e perguntar depois. Como a polícia.

Para trabalhar com a árvore, você possui algumas propriedades básicas para leitura desses dados. Pois como todo texto estilo XML ou HTML que se preze, haverá tags com texto, filhos, atributos, e etc. Todos estes dados podem ser tratados com o `ElementTree`. Quando você obtém um elemento do XML, seja com o retorno do `fromstring` ou de qualquer outra forma, você pode ler os todos aqueles dados que mencionei agora (texto, filhos, atributos e nome da tag). Para acessar estes valores, usamos, respectivamente, as propriedades `text`, `list(TAG)`, `attrib`, `tag`.

Nos casos extraordinários para obtenção dos filhos e dos atributos, usamos o `list` para converter os filhos diretos daquela tag para uma lista. Enquanto que `attrib` retorna um dicionário que liga nome do atributo ao seu valor.

O seu código, levemente modificado (eu só adaptei para ficar mais "entendível" e adicionei a leitura dos atributos), ficaria desta maneira:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with open("C1_Extrato_2_Palavras.xml") as XMLFile:
    textoArquivo = XMLFile.read()
    root = ET.fromstring(textoArquivo)


hasAttributes    = [] 
doesntHaveAttributes = []
for child in root.iter():
    if len(child.attrib) > 0:
        print(f'A tag {child.tag} possui estes atributos e valores:')
        hasAttributes.append(child.tag)
    else:
        print(f'A tag {child.tag} nao possui atributos.')
        doesntHaveAttributes.append(child.tag)

    for atributo in child.attrib:
        print('\t%s: %s' % (atributo, child.attrib[atributo]))
    print("\n")

print('=='*25)
print(f'Um total de {len(hasAttributes)} tags possuem atributos:', ', '.join(set(hasAttributes)))
print(f'E outro total de {len(doesntHaveAttributes)} tags NAO possuem atributos:', ', '.join(doesntHaveAttributes))
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, utilizei algumas funções que encontrei na documentação, e a solução foi algo parecido com esse seu código. Porém o código ficou mais curto por questão do que eu precisava era uma coisa simples e eu só não estava utilizando direito das funções disponíveis.